# Will booting Surface Book 2 from USB flash drive erase the windows product key in the firmware?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb-flash-drive, safe-mode, product-key

My surface book 2 after a factory reset was missing all basic apps like camera and windows app store, so I did something, and now it keeps restarting and doesn't load, please help, can't get it into safe mode either

Answer (score 1):

No, reinstalling Windows (or any other operating system) will not erase the embedded product key. Only a defective UEFI firmware update could do that.

Additionally, Windows restores its activation automatically from Microsoft servers, if the hardware remains (largely) unchanged—even without an embedded product key.

So just go ahead and do a clean reinstall, it’s the correct choice!

Answer (score 0):

You can start a Windows 10 system with a USB Key (you may need to turn Secure Boot off, you may not).

That will not erase your product key.

Also, if you need to reinstall Windows, the device will pick up the licensing from the Windows Licensing Server.

So you can safely go ahead with reinstall (or also a Repair Install) and you do not have anything to worry about.